# Why can't I refactor this anonymous function outside the enclosing function?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a code which uses anonymous functions which I want to test. The code follows following structure (all functions are in a big map). However, when I refactor the anonymous function as a separate function `f2` outside the bigger function `hello3` the value is not passed, as I would expect. Why is it so?
I can pass the value as a parameter, however I also want to understand the underlying principle.

```
var bigMap = {
f2: function() {
    console.log("Closed over:" + name);
},

hello1: function(name) {
     return function() {
        console.log("Closed over:" + name);
    };
},

hello2:function(name) {
    var f1 = function() {
        console.log("Closed over:" + name);
    };
    return f1;
},


hello3:function(name) {
    return this.f2;
}
};

var f = bigMap.hello1("asad");
f(); // Outputs> Closed over:asad
f = bigMap.hello2("asad");
f(); // Outputs> Closed over:asad
f = bigMap.hello3   ("asad");
f(); // Outputs> Closed over:
```

Comment: That is not what that code outputs.  `f2` needs to be referenced using `this.f2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS functions are *lexical closures*. This means that they only close over variables that are defined in a function scope phyically surrounding the function definition.

`f2` refers to the variable `name`, but it is not defined in that function or in any surrounding function, so it's not saved in the closure. Compare that to the anonymous function in `hello1` and the named function `f1` in `hello2` -- `hello1` and `hello2` each define a local variable `name`, and the enclosed functions can refer to it.

Comment: Variable hoisting in Javascript can be tricky - I'm fond of using [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) blog post to remind myself of the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about testability so much as just regular js variable scope. You can't refer to the bare word f2 anywhere because it's a property of the object 'bigMap'. In other words, if you just change 'return f2' to 'return bigMap.f2', it will return the function f2.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, this was a code bug; i had corrected it locally but pasted older version in the (now corrected) question.